# Time Discretization

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory, stochastic-approximation

I wonder why we work with constant discretization in Time Discretization 
of  numerical approximation for numerical scheme if we take not necessarily constant Discretization Is the numerical scheme (Such : Euler, Runge-Kutta4, Euler-maruyama, milstein ...) still true?

For Example Euler–Maruyama method :

they took an equidistant mesh of size N to divide a time interval [0, T] into N subintervals
which means constant discretization what will be happend if we wrok with non constant one?

I would like  to see that in point of view of Numerical analysis ??

Thank you for a clear answer, simple and detailed.